# create rdd of rdd in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

is it possible to create rdd of rdd in pyspark? 
I tried

```
rdd1=sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
rdd2=sc.parallelize([4,5,6])
rdd3=sc.parallelize([rdd1,rdd2])
```

and got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNION` method can be used to perform this action

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([4, 5, 6])
rdd3 = sc.parallelize([7, 8, 9])

rdd = sc.union([rdd1, rdd2, rdd3])
rdd.collect()

## [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As a side note it is recommended now to use the `DataFrame` or the `Dataset` API's.

Answer (score 0):

you can join 2 RDD's

rdd1.join(rdd2)